# Mask not visible in X-Ray mode

Tags: sculpting

Mask isn't visible in X-Ray mode although it is visible without X-Ray mode. I would like help with a fix for that.
[image: With X-Ray mode]

Comment: Hello, so I guess it's more a request, maybe ask for this feature here: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/